# What is meant by this sentence.?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is meant by this sentence? Leader is president or anything else?

> ... An English expedition arrived in Virginia in the year 1607. Captain Smith was among this group of a 104 settlers.
>
> Their Leader who went by the grand title of the president kept the best provisions for himself....

from *[Pocahontas, the native American Princess](https://www.storynory.com/pocahontas-native-american-princess/)* Story. A

Comment: Please tell us where this statement comes from. The context is necessary to better understand it.

Comment: from pocahontas, the native American Princess Story. An English expedition arrived in Virginia in the year 1607.Captain Smith was among this group of a 104 settlers.       Their Leader who went by the grand title of the president kept the best provisions for himself

Comment: [What does this sentence mean? What is meant by this sentence? Is the leader the president?] Please correct and clarify your sentence. The leader is the president, but I can't tell is that is Captain Smith or not from this paragraph.

Comment: "The search for a suitable site ended on 14 May 1607 when Captain Edward Maria Wingfield, president of the council, chose the Jamestown site as the location for the colony. " - [John Smith (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Smith_(explorer)) "During his Presidency Wingfield had the James Fort constructed in a month and a day. " - [Edward Maria Wingfield (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Maria_Wingfield#Arrival)

Comment: thank you @Michael Harvey .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some punctuation would help:

> Their Leader (who went by the grand title of the president) kept the best provisions for himself.

We are told that their leader kept the best food and didn't share it with the others.

We are also told an extra piece of information:  The leader used the title "President", and this is a grand title.

The Leader calls himself "President", but he isn't very grand.

In fact, if you research history you can find that the "President" was Captain Wingfield, not Captain Smith.